# Can I book a flight USA-A-B and get off at A, if I don't have a visa for country B?

Tags: usa, international-travel, covid-19, hidden-city-ticketing

We all know how ridiculous airlines prices are. A flight from “A” to “B” could be more expensive than a flight from “A” to “B” to “C” and back. I have no idea why this is happening. It is what it is I guess.

Question: I am a U.S. citizen. Based on the covid restrictions I’m allowed to visit country “A”, but not allowed to visit country “B”. I need to travel to country “A” (and I don’t care about “B”). I only need a One way flight to A.

- Option 1. Flight “USA to A”. Price: $1,000.
- Option 2. Flight “USA to A to B”. Price: $800. I have no idea why. The final destination is “B”, which I’m not allowed to visit (and I don’t care about B, since I need to go to A).

Is it ok for me to buy Option 2 Ticket, and stay in “A”? Or it is forbidden? Also, is the airline company going to let me board such a flight… after all the final destination of this flight is B. I want buy this flight with an intention to stay in A, and not go to B. Is this ok?

Comment: " I have no idea why. " - maybe it's because, for the reasons you already know, *demand* for USA -> B travel is low therefore *prices* are reduced?

Comment: If you are not allowed to B you can't make your plans real. If you don't care about B (but can be allowed, e.g. with an "airport visa") that's a starting point of discussion

Comment: One additional concern I would have, which hasn't been addressed by any of the two answers: will the OP be allowed to leave the international zone of the airport when they arrive in country A? The airport might consider that the OP is only allowed in their airport for transit, not for actually entering the country.

Comment: @AakashM That doesn't really adequately explain OP's scenario. If demand for apples is low, that doesn't explain why an orange plus an apple is cheaper than an orange.

Comment: i would guess if the airline is responsible for bringing you back if you are not allowed entry, then it will not let you on the plane in the first place.  This is the same reason we have boat immigrants

Comment: @JBentley Airlines don't consider a flight from A to C with a connection via B to be like getting an orange plus an apple. Airlines are looking at a bunch of things: the market of people who want to fly directly from A to B, the market of people who want to fly from A to C with a layover, the market of people who'd rather fly direct from A to C with another airline, and the available capacity on all relevant flights. They're trying to maximize their profit across their network, and might discount the connecting flight because it's less convenient than their competitors and in lower demand.

Comment: Title sounded like yet another "hidden city ticketing 101" question.  Clarified title to emphasize visa factor.

Comment: @JBentley the simple answer is, it doesnt need to make sense - its how the service provider charges for it.  Thats it, theres no justification needed.

Comment: Airline prices aren't expensive now. It's just that they were ridiculously low for decades. Try to go from the USA to A and B by foot/bicycle/car/train/boat, and calculate how much time and money it would cost.

Answer (score 58):

This is known as "[hidden-city ticketing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airline_booking_ploys#Hidden-city_ticketing)." Airlines aren't fond of it, and in some cases can take action by going after the frequent flyer accounts of people who do it or even [suing passengers](https://www.cntraveler.com/story/hidden-city-ticketing-everything-you-need-to-know), especially if you do this frequently, as it violates the airline's  contract of carriage, though it can be done in some cases.

There are a lot of limitations though. Checked bags which are checked through to "B" are an obvious problem, as is round-trip travel as you've already observed (the airline will automatically cancel the rest of your itinerary if you no-show the segment from "A" to "B," so this doesn't work for round-trips). There's also the risk that due to schedule changes, flight delays, or cancellations, the airline rebooks you on another routing to "B" that never takes you to "A" at all. All of this is to say that hidden city ticketing is certainly a thing, but it can go wrong in a bunch of different ways and probably shouldn't be attempted unless you're really sure you know what you're doing.

But the biggest issue here is that you say that you are not allowed into country "B" due to COVID restrictions. You haven't said what countries these are, but it's at least quite likely that the airline will confirm your eligibility to enter country "B" when you check in for your flight in the US: the airline won't even fly you from the US to "A" until they've confirmed that you have the necessary documents (both immigration and COVID-related) to enter "B." Based on what you've said, you're likely to be denied boarding.

Comment: "the airline rebooks you on another routing to "B" that never takes you to "A" at all." -- this needs to emphasized. Hidden city ticketing is taking a risk where you might need to buy a very expensive last minute ticket to get where you wanted to go. Also, another small detail: while a civil case can be brought against you, it's not criminal to do this.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130714/discussion-on-answer-by-zach-lipton-can-i-book-a-flight-usa-a-b-and-get-off-at-a).

Answer (score 29):

You will be denied boarding in the USA.  There is almost zero chance you will be allowed to travel to country A.

Airlines are legally responsibility for checking your eligibility to enter your destination country, as well as your eligibility for transiting any intermediate countries. This includes both things like visa requirements, but also COVID-based rules/restrictions/testing requirements/etc. They generally will do this at check-in, and/or at the gate when you are boarding your first international leg.

In this case, your destination is country B, with a transit in country A. As you are legally not eligible to entry country B, your entire trip will be treated as invalid, and you will be denied boarding at your origin.

Using [hidden city ticketing](https://blog.docbert.org/hidden-city-ticketing/) as this is called can be fraught with risk at the best of times. Using it across 3 different countries in the times of COVID-19 is almost certainly a bad idea.

Comment: Although I agree with the advice here, in general it's not certain the airline knows OP is not allowed to enter country B.  They do basic checks, but cannot catch all reasons for people being banned or denied entry to destination countries.

Comment: Lufthansa does NOT check eligibility for example. They make you sign that you checked, which is another issue

Comment: it is not true at all that the airlines check your eligibility to enter your destination country. of course they will check in case it's something simple like visa, but nobody will be going through detailed covid and background checks to see if you may enter country B

Comment: @user151496 Airlines are responsible for checking COVID requirements (test results, vaccination status, etc) in exactly the same way they are required to check visa requirements

Comment: speaking from a personal experience, i have used airlines during covid and the departing airports/airlines have been very negligent about covid checks for the countries where you travel to. the only time when someone has checked me for vaccination and test has been at the airport of my arrival by the border police

Comment: Seriously doubt how airlines will check for Covid requirements. The rules keep changing quite frequently, travelling passengers aren't able to keep up, doubt airlines will be able to do so. Rules can also change enroute to destination :) Also I don't suppose airlines can be held responsible for flying you back if denied entry due to Covid.

Comment: @user151496 This seems to be very much context dependent. I've seen several people left on the ground because they did not have a suitable test (this was for intra EU flights).

Comment: The airline’s initial check, in my experience, is a *simplified version* of the destination entry requirements, and it will usually (though not always) err on the side of restrictiveness.  So if it looks like your justification is at all borderline/complex, they will most likely flag you up, and the burden will be on you to convince them that you meet the entry requirements.

Comment: @DenisNardin: "Seriously doubt how airlines will check for Covid requirements"; actually, I just travelled internationally, and here is how it worked for me: we submitted our Covid results to the country we were travelling to, and they issued us a "Covid VISA" (that's not what they called it); the airline most certainly checked we had that (and yes, we have seen people left on the ground because they didn't have that paperwork)

Comment: @user151496 I would suggest you ask a question on this site like “are airlines actually checking if you meet COVID requirements for entering your travel destination” if you think not.. because from my experience, with lots of different departure and destination countries since 2020, the answer is overwhelmingly yes, airlines do check that you meet requirements for your itinerary, to the point of being annoyingly strict about minute details in most cases

Comment: @poncho I think you wanted to respond to dezkev? My comment is in agreement with yours...